# Apache redirect for url with multiple query string

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, redirection, httpd, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a url redirection for a url with multiple query strings.

```
https://www.example.com/site/template/?tab=ab&mediaId=2842247  

to NEW URL:

https://www.example.com/new-dynamic-page
```

I dont want to match any other request urls. Just needed to redirect the above url. Please suggest the best method. Am I supposed to directly use this on rewrite rule? I am thinking the special characters will create issues.

Please advice.